# Run JavaScript code in environment object

Tags: javascript, eval

In Python, the second argument of eval() and exec() can be used to specify the "namespace" (which is an object that simulates a Python environment) in which Python code is ran. How to do the same thing in JavaScript?

Comment: You can't. JavaScript has just about zero introspective capabilities.

Comment: if i understand right you need see about [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't **but** you can take advantage of the `Function` constructor to create an isolate scope and prevent access to the local scope.

From MDN on `new Function`:

> Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures
>   to their creation contexts [...] they will only be able to access their own
>   local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which
>   the Function constructor was called.

From MDN on `eval`:

> eval() is a dangerous function [...] third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible
>   attacks...

So where you do:

```
eval('1 + 2');
```

You can also do:

```
new Function('return 1 + 2')();
```

As you're creating a function you can `bind` any context to it, an object for example:

```
var data = {
  name: 'Peter'
};

var f = new Function('return "Hello "+ this.name;').bind(data);

f(); //=> "Hello Peter"
```

Comment: Since the code in the Function body still can run arbitrary JS and has access to `window` (and possibly `caller`), it'd be a long stretch to read the documentation as implying it is "not dangerous". I sure wouldn't consider it any safer than `eval`.

Comment: Yes, it's still unsafe in that aspect, but if you follow best practices and wrap everything in IIFE and only expose a unique namespace, it's still safer than a local `eval`.

Comment: As soon as I have access to `caller` (as deprecated as it may be), I have access to the "object the method was invoked upon" and all other properties (and methods) it has. The only thing that `eval` allows access to over `Function` is lexical variables who's values are *not* exposed via other means .. which is quite little, even with IIFEs and modules.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that... I put a little example here, http://jsbin.com/oGiFaQAl/2/edit. How would you access `local` or `data` in the `new Function` version?

Comment: That's super trivial example and doesn't violate the concessions in my previous comments. Try with a module that returns an actual object with properties/methods :) One the values actually enter an exposed object graph (including the DOM), then they become fair game.

Answer (score 0):

Unique argument for eval is a String. You can't do the same in Javascript. You can't hard isolate a namespace so you can end with new and overwritten data. That's why *eval* is a well known bad practice. A code worth a thousand words:

```
var x = 42;

//wrapped in a self executing function for the 'namespace'
(function(){

    var x; //creates a namespaced x

    eval('x=69; i=function(){console.log(":( function injected");}; (function(){console.log(":( function executed");})();');

    console.log("namespaced x: "+x);

})();

console.log("outer x:"+x);

i(); //This function shouldn't be here. Who wrote it? I didn't! :'(
```

More info:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1